# Django, transform from a queryset to json and use a value from a key

Tags: python, json, django

### This is my model.py

```
class Ont_Pruebas_Json(models.Model):
    usuario_id = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    data = jsonfield.JSONField()

    def __str__(self):
            return '{}'.format(self.usuario_id)
```

### On data field I am storing this:

```
{u'1': {u'user': u'user1',u'mac': u"'00:00:00:00:00:01'"}, u'2': {u'user': u'user1',u'mac': u"'00:00:00:00:00:01'"}}
```

### On my views.py

I am passing the query set this way:
context['context_json'] =  Ont_Pruebas_Json.objects.all()

How can pass from the queryset to json format so I can choose for example from 1 the key mac and get the value: 00:00:00:00:00:01.

Comment: I think this page might answer it for you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/. But why not filter the object? It is made for that .

Answer (score 0):

In general, you shouldn't store json data directly in the database. There are lots of potential problems doing this. For example, if data is missing you might not know because you didn't validate it.

You should first parse your data so that python can read it. If you are using Django Rest Framework(DRF) use a [serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/).

However, I found serializers confusing at the start so if you want to parse a queryset do so do as shown below.

```py
from .models import Ont_Pruebas_Json
import json

query = Ont_Pruebas_Json.objects.get(usuario_id ='some_user_id')
data = json.loads(str(query))
```

Comment: I am obtaining this error:  No JSON object could be decoded in the html template when rendering.